# MongoDB deleting fs.chunks where not in fs.files

Tags: mongodb

I have 10 GB of data in fs.chunks and I want to delete every document that is not on fs.files. I already removed every entry in fs.files I don't want so every id in fs.files is a file I want to keep.

So, I want something like `db.fs.chunks.remove({"_id": {$nin: fs.files._id}})` or "delete every entry in fs.chunks that doesn't exist in fs.files".

Edit:
I'm looking for the mongo equivalent of SQL `delete from fs_chunks where id not in (select id from fs_files)`.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I don't think there's an easy way to do this apart from performing a find and then iterating with forEach.  So something like:

```
function removeChunkIfNoOwner(chunk){
  //Look for the parent file
  var parentCount = db.fs.files.find({'_id' : chunk.files_id}).count();

  if (parentCount === 0 ){
     db.fs.chunks.remove({'_id': chunk._id});
     print("Removing chunk " + chunk._id);
  }
}

db.fs.chunks.find().forEach(removeChunkIfNoOwner);
```

You can see this approach should work if you create a function like this:

```
function listParentFile(chunk){
   var parent = db.fs.files.findOne({'_id' : chunk.files_id});
   printjson(parent);
}
db.fs.chunks.find().forEach(listParentFile);
```

Comment: For the record, I was wondering if you could do something like this:  db.collection.find({'fields.Tags.value.uuid' : { $in : db.collection.find({otherId : '8FAAD502-9F8D-4F84-80DC-D9C8A5801737'}, {uuid:1, _id:0}).toArray() }}); ... but it doesn't look like it works!

Comment: If you have a lot of files, you should remove the print line, it will speed up a lot the process.

Comment: For whose wondering how to use these codes snippets, just use them in a mongo shell. Invoke 'mongo' then 'show dbs' to list your databases, select the one you want to use with 'use name_of_your_db' and then copy/paste the function code in your cli

Answer (score 2):

I found this solution based on Mick's to work a bit faster for a large amount of chunks:

```
function removeChunkIfNoOwner(files_id){
  //Look for the parent file
  var parentCount = db.fs.files.find({'_id' : files_id}).count();

  if (parentCount === 0 ){
      res = db.fs.chunks.remove({'files_id':files_id})
  }
}

files = db.fs.chunks.distinct('files_id').forEach(removeChunkIfNoOwner)
```

Answer (score 2):

Using distinct would not work for me because my collection was too large. Slight modification to Bas' query worked for me.

```
function removeChunkIfNoOwner(chunk){
  var parentCount = db.fs.files.find({'_id' : chunk.files_id}).count();

  if(parentCount === 0){
    res = db.fs.chunks.remove({'files_id':chunk._id})
    print("item removed")
  }
}
files = db.fs.chunks.find({files_id:{$exists:1}},{data:0}).forEach(removeChunkIfNoOwner)
```

Comment: There is a typo in your function. Correct is: `chunks.remove({'_id':chunk._id})` instead of `chunks.remove({'files_id':chunk._id})`. The stackoverflow "edit queue is full" so I cannot suggest this edit.

Answer (score 0):

I have found this solution working **really** fast compared to the other proposed solutions:

https://gist.github.com/xelaz/8aceeacc6306c5dd92f2c91699d89a27

```js
db.getCollection('fs.chunks').aggregate([{
    $lookup: {
      from: 'fs.files',
      localField: 'files_id',
      foreignField: '_id',
      as: 'file'
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: {
      path: '$file',
      preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true
    }
  },
  {
    $match: {
      file: {
        $exists: false
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 1,
      files_id: 1
    }
  },
])toArray().forEach(function(chunk) {
  printjson(chunk);
  // db.getCollection('fs.chunks').remove({ _id: chunk._id });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

All given solutions work, but may take a long time with many affected chunks due to the single call of `db.getCollection('fs.chunks').remove(...)` for each chunk to delete.
Here is an approach to delete all affected chunks with one delete query:

```js
let chunksCollection = "fs.chunks";
let filesCollection = "fs.files";

let unrelatedChunks =
    db.getCollection(chunksCollection).aggregate(
        [
            {
                // Join with related files documents
                $lookup: {
                    from: filesCollection,
                    localField: "files_id",
                    foreignField: "_id",
                    as: "files",
                },
            },
            {
                // Filter chunks without related files document
                $match: {
                    files: {
                        $size: 0,
                    },
                },
            },
            {
                // Project files_id
                $project: {
                    files_id: "$files_id",
                },
            },
        ]
    )
        .toArray();

// Create an array with files_id
let files_id_OfUnrelatedChunks = unrelatedChunks.map(document => document.files_id)

// Delete all chunks with no longer existing files_id
db.getCollection(chunksCollection).deleteMany({"files_id": {$in: files_id_OfUnrelatedChunks}})
```